# 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', How do I fix the error?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench

I am running my web application in a virtual environment and I restarted my sql server to see if this error would not persist. It didn't work and I cannot find anything online that seems to fix my problem.

The full error is:

> 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system
> error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number
> (_ssl.c:2607)

When I run my website I have a login validation and that part seems to be running as I can login with a valid username and password. But all the information I load from the server doesn't work and I am not even getting a status returned if the login information is not valid. Would anyone be able to help me with this? Also I am relatively new to the coding world and I'm not well versed on what questions I can and can't post on Stack Overflow. If this question doesn't belong here, I would appreciate it if you would direct me to another forum. Thank You!

I also found another error: unable to import MySQL.connector. I think this is the problem. The code for where I connect to the server and setup the connector is here:

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="root123",
    database="foodtrackdb"
)
```

Comment: I also found another error: unable to import MySQL.connector. I think this is the problem. The code for where I connect to the server and setup the connector is here:

Comment: What language are you programming in, and why haven't you added it at a tag?

Comment: I was coding in python good to know, I should've added it as a tag. I figured out that I had pip uninstall all the python connectors and reinstall them for some reason

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you did here?  I'm having the same issue and I removed mysql-connector and mysql-connector-python and also restarted apache2 but am having the same error.

Comment: Hi Jorvis, I realized that every time I want to access the DB I have to create a new connection and once I'm done say adding something to the db or retrieving the data I have to close the connection. In my website every time the request was ent I was only opening the connection once and never closing it. So I decided to open and close the connection in every function where I was accessing the db. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL Server, run the following:

```
set global max_allowed_packet=67108864;
```

Comment: My own answer helped! I did not know I had answered this a year earlier!

Comment: didn't help me on py3.10